# Why shadow catcher effect is messy in Bender?

Tags: compositing-nodes, shadowcatcher

i am new to Blender , i render text object with shadow catcher , but fount it was so messy compared to the one without shadow catcher

**Here is the original complete one**
[image: Original one]

**Here is the one with shadow catcher**
[image: one with shadow cather]

As you can see ,shadow effect is messy and darker

**what i have tried to solve this ?**

1.I use composite node to separate shadow and object and decrease the intensity of shadow , but i meet such new problem!There is white edge !!
[image]
[image]

2.maybe i can create a duplicated text object and offset to inside direction and use that one's shadow to avoid white edge , but it is so troublesome..

3.maybe i can try to separate alpha of object and subtract it with shadow catcher one , and then affect shadow so that avoid white edge , but it is troublesome too

Is there any efficient method to make shadow catcher effect smoother and more beautiful?

Comment: the most common use for shadow catchers is compositing 3D rendered objects on top of real/preexisting footage. Seems like your scene is completely CG – is there a specific reason you are using a shadow catcher?

Comment: Well, generate multiple object PNG render images in Python , maybe  10 thousands single image, so i must need shadow catcher